# In raphaeljs, is there a way to place text within an object to keep rollover state

Tags: javascript, oop, svg, raphael

In creating a svg map using raphael js where I have hover states. How ever I am trying to write the country names onto the map. The problem I am facing is the names become their own object and block the country so I loose hover and click when the cursor is directly over the text. Is there a way where I can draw the text and not have it block the map. I've tried set() but with no sucess.

Thanks,

What I have below doesn't have the text() or print() included:

```
var r = Raphael('map', 1450, 2180);
    arr = new Array();

for (var country in paths) {

    var obj = r.path(paths[country].path);
    countryName = paths[country].name;
    color = paths[country].color;
    scolor = paths[country].stroke;

    obj.attr({fill:color,stroke:scolor,
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round'});

    arr[obj.id] = country;

    obj
    .hover(function(){
        console.log(arr[this.id]);
        this.animate({
            fill: paths[arr[this.id]].hover
        }, 300);

    }, function(){
        this.animate({
            fill: paths[arr[this.id]].color
        }, 300);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `pointer-events` attribute to `none` for the text elements.
Documentation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty